# wordpress theme is not installing & showing error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

(The link you followed has expired). this error showing when I am installing a theme in WordPress what's the solution of it?

(The link you followed has expired). this error showing when I am installing a theme in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from most probably the upload memory limit size. You can increase memory limit in several ways. Check this link for more info

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-link-you-followed-has-expired-error-in-wordpress/